# Custom popup in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, treeview

Is there any way to create a custom PopUp in JavaFX? I can't use tooltip, since I would like it to appear on double click, also I would like a different style than the standard tooltip.

My demands for the popup are:
1. If the user double click, show the popup
2. if the user clicks outside the popup, hide it

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) guide on all the different types of popups.

Comment: Citing your sources is welcome but you should always paraphrase some of the info in case the link ever breaks

Answer (score 0):

Use [Popup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Popup.html).

```
Popup popup = new Popup();

// add content (you can add as many nodes as you want)
popup.getContent().add(new Label("Hello Popup!"));

// show (move this to the double-click listener)
popup.show(primaryStage);

// hide (move this to the click listener)
popup.hide();
```